# правильное употребление "и"

Tags: грамматика

15. В границах водоохранных зон запрещаются:
    ..............
    4) движение и стоянка транспортных средств (кроме специальных транспортных средств), за исключением их движения по дорогам и стоянки на дорогах и в специально оборудованных местах, имеющих твердое покрытие;

К чему относится "имеющих твердое покрытие", только к специально оборудованным местам или к дорогам тоже?